# Using anonymous Cognito identity to upload files to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have an iOS client that is successfully able to upload files to S3 using anonymous Cognito Identity and using Amplify SDK.
Now I am trying to simulate the same upload using CLI and failing miserably.
Here is what I am doing:

1. Get identity for give pool ID:

```
        > aws cognito-identity get-id --identity-pool-id us-east-1:XXX-XXX

        {
            "IdentityId": "us-east-1:YYY-YYY"
        }
```

2. Get credentials for this identity:

```
        > aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity --identity-id  "us-east-1:YYY-YYY" --region "us-east-1"

        {
            "IdentityId": "us-east-1:YYY-YYY",
            "Credentials": {
                "AccessKeyId": "KEY-KEY-KEY",
                "SecretKey": "SECRET-SECRET-SECRET",
                "SessionToken": "long session token here",
                "Expiration": "2030-01-09T01:28:11+02:00"
            }
        }
```

3. Try uploading a file with returned credentials:

```
        > AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="KEY-KEY-KEY" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="SECRET-SECRET-SECRET" aws s3 --region us-east-1 cp /tmp/txt.txt s3://my-public-bucket/txt.txt

        upload failed: /tmp/txt.txt to s3://my-public-bucket/txt.txt An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

The result I am getting is `InvalidAccessKeyId`: `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.` Should the key be registered before usage? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
It also requires using the session token and not only key and secret. So, the last command is changed into this:

```
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="KEY-KEY-KEY" \
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="SECRET-SECRET-SECRET"\
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="long session token here"\
aws s3 --region us-east-1 cp /tmp/txt.txt s3://my-public-bucket/txt.txt
```